# Pegar o item selecionado no Jcombobox

Tags: java, swing

Como eu faço para pegar o item selecionado pelo usuário nesse Combobox?

```
opcaoBusca.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"Op\u00E7\u00E3o da Busca", "N\u00FAmero do Pedido"}));

        entBusca = new JFormattedTextField();
        entBusca.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                entBusca.setText("");
            }
        });
        entBusca.setEnabled(false);

        ListaBox = new JComboBox<String>();
        ListaBox.addItem("Selecione");
        try {  
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.1:1521:banco1","root","root");

            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet RS = null;
            RS = stmt.executeQuery("select codplpag from pcplpag  "); 

            while(RS.next()){  
                ListaBox.addItem(RS.getString("codplpag"));  
                //String codplpag  = RS.getString("codplpag");
                //System.out.println("saida de dados" +codplpag);

            }  

            stmt.close();  
            con.close();  
        }  

        catch(SQLException e)  
        {  
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Erro Cmdo SQL "+e.getMessage());  
        }  
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e){  
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Driver não encontrado");  
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para obter o índice selecionado:

```
int indiceSelecionado = seuComboBox.getSelectedIndex();
```

Ou, para obter pelo item (valor/palavra):

```
String itemSelecionado = seuComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

---

Outra forma é usar um `ItemListener` para efetuar alguma ação quando o usuário selecionar uma opção diferente no `JComboBox`. Para isto, há o método `getItem()`.

Código de exemplo:

```
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ComboBox extends JFrame {

    public ComboBox(){
        JComboBox combobox = new JComboBox();
        combobox.addItem("Cachorro");
        combobox.addItem("Gato");
        combobox.addItem("Peixe");

        // Listener para 'fazer algo' sempre que for selecionada uma opção no JComboBox
        combobox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) // para evitar duplicações
                    System.out.println("Você escolheu a opção " + e.getItem());
            }
        });

        // Propriedades do JFrame
        setSize(150, 100);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().add(combobox);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ComboBox().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Renam quando eu coloco  dessa forma, não apresenta nada na saida a não o nome Seleção
//---codigo-------
   while(RS.next()){  
    ListaBox.addItem(RS.getString("codplpag"));  
    //String codplpag  = RS.getString("codplpag");        
   }  
   String selecao = ListaBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
   System.out.println("esse e o item : "  + selecao);

Comment: e isso mesmo que está acontecendo!!! como eu mudo isso não entendi muito bem.

Comment: Poxa Renam, muito bom cara valeu mesmo agora só mais uma dúvida como eu faço pra pegar esse valor que foi selecionado pra salvar no banco de dados através de um update ?
--codigo--
int registro = stmt.executeUpdate("update pcpedc set codplpag =  "no caso a opção selecionada estaria aqui"

      + " where numped=" + consPCPEDC);

Comment: Renan muito obrigado brother, valeu mesmo um forte abraço Brow.